# what does the regular expression "^[Ee][Pp]{1,}[\d1-9]{7,9}" mean

Tags: javascript

what does this regular expression mean?

```
"^[Ee][Pp]{1,}[\d1-9]{7,9}"
```

If these are inclusion patterns lets say run if input parameters match with the pattern. I understand [Ee][Pp] but beyond that I am lost. I dont get what is {1,} [\d1-9] and {7,9}

This is probably a real dumb question

Comment: I would suggest you something like http://www.regexr.com where you can just past it in and then hover over every token, which will show you a popup which describes everything you need.

Comment: Or http://regex101.com/r/bE0uS2

Comment: `[\d1-9]` is redundant; `1-9` are all digits, so it could just be `\d`.

Comment: Also by using the case insensitive flag, the letter characters wouldn't have to be repeated.

Comment: @Luke I agree with him

Comment: So it would be safe to say "^[EePp]{1,}[\d-9]{7,9}" would include P0000005 and E0000022 correct?

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, a pair of numbers in curly braces indicates a minimum and/or maximum number of repeats. The number before the comma is the minimum, and the number after is the maximum. If one of the numbers is omitted, there's no limit in that direction.

Specifically, `{1,}` means 1 or more (equivalent to `+`), and `{7,9}` means anywhere between 7 and 9 repeats. Some examples of strings that might match this regular expression might be:

```
EP1234567
epppppppp123456789example
```